# Understanding when to use the chain rule when differentiating trig functions.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem that involves finding the maximum angle that subtends two points.  The two points are $b = (0, 5)$ and $t = (0, 14)$.  The third point is the point that is changing, and is $e = (x, 0)$.  The angle being maximized is the angle $\angle bet$.

I understand that this angle can be defined with:
$$\theta = \arctan \frac{14} x - \arctan \frac 5 x$$

To me, I see $\theta$ as the result of a function:
$$f(x) = \arctan \frac {14} x - \arctan \frac 5 x$$

So I'd differentiate it like this:
$$f^\prime(x) = \frac {1}{1 + (\frac{14}{x})^2} - \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{5}{x})^2}$$
when it should be this, because the differentiation is implicit and you have to apply the chain rule:
$$\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac {1}{1 + (\frac{14}{x})^2} \cdot -\frac{14}{x^2} - \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{5}{x})^2} \cdot -\frac{5}{x}$$
So, when do you use implicit differentiation and when do you not?

Comment: Don't forget to multiply by the derivative of the expression you're taking the arctangent of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a serious differentiation error. You need to use the chain rule. The derivative of $\arctan \dfrac {14}x$ is $\dfrac{1}{1+ (\frac{14}{x})^2}$ times the derivative of $\dfrac  {14}x$ which is $- \dfrac{14}{x^2}$. Same with the other term. There is nothing implicit about this procedure. The angle is defined *explicitly* as a function of $x$.

Comment: I see.  I was thinking that if the derivative of $\arctan x = \frac 1 {1+ x^2}$, then I can plug in $\frac {14} x$ in for $x$ and get $\frac 1 {1 + (\frac {14} x)^2}$, which obviously doesn't make sense because I've essentially said $x = \frac {14} x$.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImplicitDifferentiation.html

It comes up in differential equations when finding an explicit representation of the nth variable in terms of n-1 variables is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I wasn't thinking of this as the composite of two functions.  The two functions involved are $f(x) = 14/x$ and $g(x) = \arctan(f(x))$.  Then applying the chain rule as normal makes sense.

Comment: FYI, this may get closed since it isn't an answer to your question. You could either follow up with a comment to the original question, or even (now that you know the solution) answer your own question.